# Permanent error with maftools

Tags: r, maftools

I want to remove variant including in copy number changed area by maftools but I am permanently get this error

```
> tcga.ab.3009.het = inferHeterogeneity(maf = laml_res, tsb = tsb, segFile = seg, vafCol = 'T_VAF')
CN data for following samples not found. Ignoring them ..
 [1] "LP6008337-DNA_A07" "LP6008460-DNA_F02" "LP6008460-DNA_G03" "LP6008460-DNA_D01" "LP6008202-DNA_B03" "LP6008460-DNA_A04"
 [7] "LP6005935-DNA_G02" "LP6008334-DNA_B02" "LP6008269-DNA_F06" "LP6008336-DNA_F02" "LP6005334-DNA_H01" "LP6005500-DNA_D03"
[13] "LP6008334-DNA_A04" "LP6008336-DNA_G01" "LP6008336-DNA_H02" "LP6007600"        
Processing LP6008334-DNA_D02..
Error in data.table::foverlaps(x = tsb.dat, y = seg, by.x = c("Chromosome",  : 
  The last two columns in by.x should correspond to the 'start' and 'end' intervals in data.table 'x' and must be integer/numeric type.


> head(dat.tsb[1:3,1:6])
   Tumor_Sample_Barcode Chromosome Start_Position End_Position Reference_Allele Tumor_Seq_Allele2
1:    LP6008334-DNA_A03       chr5       70858261     70858261                -                 A
2:    LP6008334-DNA_A03      chr10      115987869    115987869                A                 -
3:    LP6008334-DNA_A03      chr16       29859285     29859287              ACC                 -
>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What are the types of `Start_Position` and `End_Position` columns? You can get that info with `str(your_table)`.

Comment: Thank you they are integer (start and end of genomic range where the mutation supposed to be happened)